# Using the squants library, how do I specify a specific unit of measure for a method?

Tags: scala, latitude-longitude, angle

I have some code which abuses `Double` in much the same way as `String` is abused as a *the goto* for typeless types. Using `Double` in this way results in lots of subtle and/or hidden issues, typically arising as pernicious runtime errors. This is what the two methods looks like now:

```
object Geospatial {
  def calculateDistance(
    coordinate1Longitude: Double,
    coordinate1Latitude: Double,
    coordinate2Longitude: Double,
    coordinate2Latitude: Double
  ): (Double, Double, Double) = {
    //code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
    //returns (distance in meters, initial bearing in zero-based radians, final bearing in zero-based radians)
    ???
  }

  def calculateCoordinate(
    coordinate1Longitude: Double,
    coordinate1Latitude: Double,
    angle: Double,
    distance: Double
  ): (Double, Double) = {
    //code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
    //returns angle in radians for longitude and latitude
    ???
  }
}
```

As you can imagine, if the client was to call either of these methods and had not already properly converted to meters and radians and/or ALSO forgot the methods were returning values in meters and radians, the client would get incorrect results.

So, I would like to significantly improve the type safety of the above methods; i.e. I would like the client to receive compile time errors if/when the client attempts to make a call to either of these methods where the types they are passing don't precisely match the types these methods require. In that spirit, I've rewritten the methods (and their context) to be more typed (but still not enough):

```
object Geospatial {
  type AngleRadiansCentered = Double
    //angle's range is restricted to [-Math.PI until Math.PI]
  type AngleRadiansPositive = Double
    //angle's range is restricted to [0.0d until (Math.PI * 2.0d)]

  type LongitudeRadians = AngleRadiansCentered
  type LatitudeRadians = AngleRadiansCentered  //angle's range must be _further_ restricted to -(Math.PI / 2.0d) until (Math.PI / 2.0d)

  def calculateDistance(
    coordinate1: (Longitude, Latitude),
    coordinate2: (Longitude, Latitude)
  ): (Meters, AngleRadiansPositive, AngleRadiansPositive) = {
    //Legacy code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
    //returns (distance, initial bearing, final bearing)
    ???
  }

  def calculateCoordinate(
    coordinate1: (Longitude, Latitude),
    bearing: AngleRadiansPositive,
    distance: Meters
  ): (Longitude, Latitude) = {
    //Legacy code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
    ???
  }
}
```

As I've been working this problem, I recently discovered the [squants](http://www.squants.com/) library. I'm thinking I would like to rewrite the above code using [squants](http://www.squants.com/). However, after spending an hour or so reading the sparse [squants](http://www.squants.com/) documentation (at least regarding relevant examples to my context), I couldn't make any reasonable leaps on how to apply it to this problem. For example, how do I specify as a method parameter it only accepts `Meters` (and not the more generic, `Length`). IOW, I am looking for type safety, not conversion between types (although that is something I will be doing just outside of these methods).

I couldn't find any [squants](http://www.squants.com/) example code snippits from which I could derive what I'm  needing. And I'm not asking for the full solution. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. First, I need to know if [squants](http://www.squants.com/) is really the right API to be using. And then, if it is, I need enough help to push me in the right general direction so I can figure out the rest of the solution space.

I do intend to at least use case classes to replace all of the instances of `Double`. Before I do that though, I would like to know if there are idiomatic ways I could be doing that with the [squants](http://www.squants.com/) library.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not accept any `Length` and then convert it to a `Meter` using the [`toMeters` method](https://github.com/garyKeorkunian/squants/blob/a4e3cdc6a39d5b4a4fa7f0cdede065fd32d762ab/shared/src/main/scala/squants/space/Length.scala#L71)?

Comment: I had considered that, but wasn't able to see how to guarantee the client knew the function was expecting meters and radians explicitly. However, now that I have seen Alvaro's answer, I think I kind of get what how what you are suggesting might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the same process and this is what I found: The squants library, at least by itself, will not give you *exactly* what you're looking for. The typesafety it provides, refers specifically to not mixing different types of quantities, but the actual unit within the same dimension is not as important.

That said, after working with it for a while I realized that the approach it takes was actually the correct one for my needs. You still get the important type safety: Keeping values within their dimension. And mixing different units within the same dimension is still safe, since the way you create a `Length` unit, is by using one of the "constructors", like `Meters` or `Centimeter`. The internal representation shouldn't matter. You are working with a `Length` (the important part). If you want the raw `Meter` (saving to the database?), call `toMeters` at that time. There is no loss in type safety by doing so.

Comment: Tysvm for your answer. I think I understand what you are saying. To make sure, though, I "refactored" the above code to incorporate what you are saying while also adding the domain restrictions. When you have a moment, would you mind looking at it and letting me know if I'm close. Any feedback on it would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/1pYrXTrC

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium The code looks about right. I would probably not "convert" for the `require` checks: `Radians(0.0d) <= angle) && (angle < Radians(Math.PI * 2.0d))` ... minor, but i think it helps keep all the operations within the library.

Comment: Awesome! I completely agree. I am now going to add an answer with the my code at pastebin.com (but fixed per your suggestion) just for completeness. I will select your answer as your direction is what enabled me to see how to create the squants code. Tysvm!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Alvaro Carrasco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833386/501113), I was able to see my initial approach to use the [squants](http://www.squants.com/) library was slightly askew ([located on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/1pYrXTrC), and has been fixed). Below what the concrete solution ended up looking like:

```
import squants.space.{Radians, Meters}
import squants.{Angle, Length}

object Geospatial {
  case class Longitude(angle: Angle) {
    require(
      (Radians(-Math.PI) <= angle) && (angle < Radians(Math.PI)),
      "angle.inRadians must be greater than or equal to -Math.PI and less than Math.PI"
    )
  }
  case class Latitude(angle: Angle) {
    require(
      (Radians(-(Math.PI * 0.5d)) <= angle) && (angle < Radians(Math.PI * 0.5d)),
      "angle.inRadians must be greater than or equal to -(Math.PI * 0.5d) and less than (Math.PI * 0.5d)"
    )
  }
  case class Distance(length: Length) {
    require(
      Meters(0.0d) <= length,
      "length.inMeters must be greater than or equal to 0.0d"
    )
  }
  case class Bearing(angle: Angle) {
    require(
      (Radians(0.0d) <= angle) && (angle < Radians(Math.PI * 2.0d)),
      "angle.inRadians must be greater than or equal to 0.0d and less than (Math.PI * 2.0d)"
    )
  }

  case class Coordinate(longitude: Longitude, latitude: Latitude)

  def calculateDistance(
    coordinate1: Coordinate,
    coordinate2: Coordinate
  ): (Distance, Bearing, Bearing) = {
    def calculateDistanceUsingLegacyCodeRifeWithDoubles(
      coordinate1LongitudeInRadians: Double,
      coordinate1LatitudeInRadians: Double,
      coordinate2LongitudeInRadians: Double,
      coordinate2LatitudeInRadians: Double
    ): (Double, Double, Double) = {
      //Legacy code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
      //returns (distance, initial bearing, final bearing)
      (1.0d, 1.0d, 2.0d) //TODO: replace with real calculation results
    }
    val (coordinate1InRadians, coordinate2InRadians) = (
      (coordinate1.longitude.angle.toRadians, coordinate1.latitude.angle.toRadians),
      (coordinate2.longitude.angle.toRadians, coordinate2.latitude.angle.toRadians)
    )
    val (distanceInMeters, bearingInitialInRadians, bearingFinalInRadians) =
      calculateDistanceUsingLegacyCodeRifeWithDoubles(
        coordinate1InRadians._1,
        coordinate1InRadians._2,
        coordinate2InRadians._1,
        coordinate2InRadians._2
      )
    (
      Distance(Meters(distanceInMeters)),
      Bearing(Radians(bearingInitialInRadians)),
      Bearing(Radians(bearingFinalInRadians))
    )
  }

  def calculateCoordinate(
    coordinate1: Coordinate,
    bearingInitial: Bearing,
    distance: Distance
  ): Coordinate = {
    def calculateCoordinateUsingLegacyCodeRifeWithDoubles(
      coordinate1Longitude: Double,
      coordinate1Latitude: Double,
      bearingInitialInRadians: Double,
      distanceInMeters: Double
    ): (Double, Double) = {
      //Legacy code encapsulated here only works with meters and radians
      //returns (longitude, latitude)
      (-1.0d, 1.0d) //TODO: replace with real calculation results
    }
    val (coordinate1InRadians, bearingInitialInRadians, distanceInMeters) = (
      (coordinate1.longitude.angle.toRadians, coordinate1.latitude.angle.toRadians),
      bearingInitial.angle.toRadians,
      distance.length.toMeters
    )
    val (longitude, latitude) =
      calculateCoordinateUsingLegacyCodeRifeWithDoubles(
        coordinate1InRadians._1,
        coordinate1InRadians._2,
        bearingInitialInRadians,
        distanceInMeters
      )
    Coordinate(Longitude(Radians(longitude)), Latitude(Radians(latitude)))
  }
}
```